# Problem with Facebook Toolkit

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I am using the latest Facebook Toolkit. I want to retrieve all albums of the current user.
I use `FacebookService.GetPhotoAlbums()`, but the result has an itemcount of 0 :-/ No error is raised.

Do you have similar experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain the "user_photos" extended permissions to do this. You can go to http://fbgraph.computerbeacon.net/tutorial/section2/ for details of doing this with the [Facebook Graph Toolkit](http://fbgraph.computerbeacon.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I would *strongly* advise moving away from the FDT. Not only is it rarely updated, but it does not support the new OpenGraph API. There is a new [OpenGraph-based library](http://opengraph.codeplex.com/) another party is working on, but I can't vouch for its quality. The simplicity of the new API also makes it fairly straightforward to roll your own interface.